# How to run JSP code every 15mins once without running it

Tags: jsp

How to run JSP code every 15mins once without running it. I want to execute a jsp program code periodically every 15mins once.

Comment: This is weird requirement, you shouldn't relay on this. it seems you are trying to do this for some other site,and you don't have actual code

Answer (score 2):

Java code [doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) belong in a JSP file. Just move that code into a real Java class. This way you can use [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) in a [`ServletContextListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) to execute it periodically.

```
@WebListener
public class Config implements ServletContextListener {

    private ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Task(), 0, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        scheduler.shutdownNow();
    }

}
```

Where `Task` class implements [`Runnable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html).

```
public class Task implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        // Do your job here.
    }

}
```

Or if your Java EE container is capable of this, use the container-provided job scheduling capabilities.  The detailed answer depends on the container which you're using.

Answer (score -2):

You can write a JAVA code which will trigger the JSP code periodically.If you have interest in this solution I can help you to do this (giving the sample code).

Comment: My point was to make an java application which will execute the JSP code(calling the URL) periodically.